# How to add multiple lines of text in GWT celltable EditTextCell?

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable, gwt-edittext

I have a celltable displayed with data. I want to edit the cells to give information in multiple lines.

Example:
key1=value1| In next line add anoter key: 
key2=value2|

After editing the values, when the celltable is displayed/ redrawn then the info should be displayed as above in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved part of the issue. I am using CellTable with customized TextAreaEditCell. Now I am able to enter multiple lines of data. But when it goes to database or when celltable displayed the information, the info is in sequential form.

### Example:

when i enter data like this in TestAreaCell:
abcd 
In next line, enter efgh then the

### Output when displayed is:

abcdefgh

Issue: Seems the enter key is not getting considered:

My TextAreaEditCell class is below. Please let me know if any corrections need to be done.

I have solved part of the issue. I am using CellTable with customized TextAreaEditCell. Now I am able to enter multiple lines of data. But when it goes to database or when celltable displayed the information, the info is in sequential form.

### Example:

when i enter data like this in TestAreaCell:
abcd 
In next line, enter efgh then the

### Output when displayed is:

abcdefgh

Issue: Seems the enter key is not getting considered:

My TestAreaEditCell class is below. Please let me know if any corrections need to be done.

```
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractEditableCell;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context; 
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT; 
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element; 
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.EventTarget; 
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.InputElement; 
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent; 
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.TextAreaElement;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes; 
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.SafeHtmlTemplates; 
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml; 
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder; 
import com.google.gwt.text.shared.SafeHtmlRenderer; 
import com.google.gwt.text.shared.SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer; 

/** 
 * An editable text cell. Click to edit, escape to cancel, return to commit. 
 */ 
public class TextAreaEditCell  extends 
AbstractEditableCell<String, TextAreaEditCell .ViewData> { 

    interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates { 
        //@Template("<input type=\"text\" value=\"{0}\" tabindex=\"-1\"></input>")  
        //SafeHtml input(String value);

        //using textarea (instead of text) to add multiple lines of data in a cell.
        @Template("<textarea tabindex=\"-1\" rows=\"{1}\" cols=\"{2}\" >{0}</textarea>")
        SafeHtml input(String value, Integer rows, Integer cols); 
    } 

    /** 
     * The view data object used by this cell. We need to store both the text and 
     * the state because this cell is rendered differently in edit mode. If we did 
     * not store the edit state, refreshing the cell with view data would always 
     * put us in to edit state, rendering a text box instead of the new text 
     * string. 
     */ 
    static class ViewData { 

        private boolean isEditing; 

        /** 
         * If true, this is not the first edit. 
         */ 
        private boolean isEditingAgain; 

        /** 
         * Keep track of the original value at the start of the edit, which might be 
         * the edited value from the previous edit and NOT the actual value. 
         */ 
        private String original; 

        private String text; 

        /** 
         * Construct a new ViewData in editing mode. 
         * 
         * @param text the text to edit 
         */ 
        public ViewData(String text) { 
            this.original = text; 
            this.text = text; 
            this.isEditing = true; 
            this.isEditingAgain = false; 

        } 

        @Override 
        public boolean equals(Object o) { 
            if (o == null) { 
                return false; 
            } 
            ViewData vd = (ViewData) o; 
            return equalsOrBothNull(original, vd.original) 
            && equalsOrBothNull(text, vd.text) && isEditing == vd.isEditing 
            && isEditingAgain == vd.isEditingAgain; 
        } 

        public String getOriginal() { 
            return original; 
        } 

        public String getText() { 
            return text; 
        } 

        @Override 
        public int hashCode() { 
            return original.hashCode() + text.hashCode() 
            + Boolean.valueOf(isEditing).hashCode() * 29 
            + Boolean.valueOf(isEditingAgain).hashCode(); 
        } 

        public boolean isEditing() { 
            return isEditing; 
        } 

        public boolean isEditingAgain() { 
            return isEditingAgain; 
        } 

        public void setEditing(boolean isEditing) { 
            boolean wasEditing = this.isEditing; 
            this.isEditing = isEditing; 

            // This is a subsequent edit, so start from where we left off. 
            if (!wasEditing && isEditing) { 
                isEditingAgain = true; 
                original = text; 
            } 
        } 

        public void setText(String text) { 
            this.text = text; 
        } 

        private boolean equalsOrBothNull(Object o1, Object o2) { 
            return (o1 == null) ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2); 
        } 
    } 

    private static Template template; 
    private int inputWidth; 
    private int inputLength;

    public int getInputWidth() { 
        return inputWidth; 
    } 

    public void setInputWidth(int inputWidth) { 
        this.inputWidth = inputWidth; 
    } 

    public int getInputLength() { 
        return inputLength; 
    } 

    public void setInputLength(int inputLength) { 
        this.inputLength = inputLength; 
    } 

    private final SafeHtmlRenderer<String> renderer; 

    /** 
     * Construct a new EditTextCell that will use a 
     * {@link SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer}. 
     */ 
    public TextAreaEditCell() {    

        this(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance(), 1, 20); 
        this.inputWidth = 10;
        this.inputLength =2;    
    }

    private int rows, cols;

    /** 
     * Construct a new TextAreaEditCell that will use a given {@link SafeHtmlRenderer} 
     * to render the value when not in edit mode. 
     *  
     * @param renderer a {@link SafeHtmlRenderer SafeHtmlRenderer<String>} 
     *          instance 
     */ 
    public TextAreaEditCell(SafeHtmlRenderer<String> renderer, int r, int c) { 
        super("click", "keyup", "keydown", "blur"); 
        rows = r; 
        cols = c; 


        if (template == null) { 
            template = GWT.create(Template.class); 
        } 
        if (renderer == null) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("renderer == null"); 
        } 
        this.renderer = renderer; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean isEditing(Context context, Element parent, String value) { 
        ViewData viewData = getViewData(context.getKey()); 
        return viewData == null ? false : viewData.isEditing(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, 
            NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) { 

        Object key = context.getKey(); 
        ViewData viewData = getViewData(key); 
        if (viewData != null && viewData.isEditing()) { 
            // Handle the edit event. 
            editEvent(context, parent, value, viewData, event, valueUpdater); 
        } else { 
            String type = event.getType(); 
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode(); 
            boolean enterPressed = "keyup".equals(type) ;
            //  && keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER; 


            if ("click".equals(type) || enterPressed) { 
                // Go into edit mode. 
                if (viewData == null) { 
                    viewData = new ViewData(value); 
                    setViewData(key, viewData); 
                } else { 
                    viewData.setEditing(true); 
                } 
                edit(context, parent, value); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) { 

        // Get the view data. 
        Object key = context.getKey(); 
        ViewData viewData = getViewData(key); 
        if (viewData != null && !viewData.isEditing() && value != null 
                && value.equals(viewData.getText())) { 
            clearViewData(key); 
            viewData = null; 
        } 

        if (viewData != null) { 
            String text = viewData.getText(); 
            if (viewData.isEditing()) { 
                /* 
                 * Do not use the renderer in edit mode because the value of a text 
                 * input element is always treated as text. SafeHtml isn't valid in the 
                 * context of the value attribute. 
                 */ 
                sb.append(template.input(text, inputLength, inputWidth)); 
            } 
            else { 
                // The user pressed enter, but view data still exists. 
                sb.append(renderer.render(text)); 
            } 
        } else if (value != null) { 
            sb.append(renderer.render(value)); 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean resetFocus(Context context, Element parent, String value) { 

        if (isEditing(context, parent, value)) { 
            getInputElement(parent).focus(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Convert the cell to edit mode. 
     * 
     * @param context the {@link Context} of the cell 
     * @param parent the parent element 
     * @param value the current value 
     */ 
    protected void edit(Context context, Element parent, String value) { 
        setValue(context, parent, value); 
        TextAreaElement input = getInputElement(parent); 
        input.focus(); 
        input.select(); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Convert the cell to non-edit mode. 
     *  
     * @param context the context of the cell 
     * @param parent the parent Element 
     * @param value the value associated with the cell 
     */ 
    private void cancel(Context context, Element parent, String value) { 
        clearInput(getInputElement(parent)); 
        setValue(context, parent, value); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Clear selected from the input element. Both Firefox and IE fire spurious 
     * onblur events after the input is removed from the DOM if selection is not 
     * cleared. 
     * 
     * @param input the input element 
     */ 
    private native void clearInput(Element input) /*-{ 
    if (input.selectionEnd) 
      input.selectionEnd = input.selectionStart; 
    else if ($doc.selection) 
      $doc.selection.clear(); 
  }-*/; 

    /** 
     * Commit the current value. 
     *  
     * @param context the context of the cell 
     * @param parent the parent Element 
     * @param viewData the {@link ViewData} object 
     * @param valueUpdater the {@link ValueUpdater} 
     */ 
    private void commit(Context context, Element parent, ViewData viewData, 
            ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) { 
        String value = updateViewData(parent, viewData, false); 
        clearInput(getInputElement(parent)); 
        setValue(context, parent, viewData.getOriginal()); 
        if (valueUpdater != null) { 
            valueUpdater.update(value); 
        } 
    } 

    private void editEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, 
            ViewData viewData, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) { 
        String type = event.getType(); 
        boolean keyUp = "keyup".equals(type); 
        boolean keyDown = "keydown".equals(type); 
        if (keyUp || keyDown) { 
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode(); 

            /*      if (keyUp && keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) { 
                // Commit the change. 
                commit(context, parent, viewData, valueUpdater); 
            } 
            else*/ 
            if (keyUp && keyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ESCAPE) { 
                // Cancel edit mode. 
                String originalText = viewData.getOriginal(); 
                if (viewData.isEditingAgain()) { 
                    viewData.setText(originalText); 
                    viewData.setEditing(false); 
                } else { 
                    setViewData(context.getKey(), null); 
                } 
                cancel(context, parent, value); 
            } else { 
                // Update the text in the view data on each key. 
                updateViewData(parent, viewData, true); 
            } 
        } else if ("blur".equals(type)) { 
            // Commit the change. Ensure that we are blurring the input element and 
            // not the parent element itself. 
            EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget(); 
            if (Element.is(eventTarget)) { 
                Element target = Element.as(eventTarget); 
                if ("textarea".equals(target.getTagName().toLowerCase())) { 
                    commit(context, parent, viewData, valueUpdater); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Get the input element in edit mode. 
     */ 
    private TextAreaElement  getInputElement(Element parent) { 
        return parent.getFirstChild().<TextAreaElement> cast(); 
    } 

    /** 
     * Update the view data based on the current value. 
     * 
     * @param parent the parent element 
     * @param viewData the {@link ViewData} object to update 
     * @param isEditing true if in edit mode 
     * @return the new value 
     */ 
    private String updateViewData(Element parent, ViewData viewData, 
            boolean isEditing) { 
        TextAreaElement input = (TextAreaElement) parent.getFirstChild();       
        String value = input.getValue(); 
        viewData.setText(value); 
        viewData.setEditing(isEditing); 
        return value; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing; although not exactly the same. So maybe SOMETHING like this will work.

You need to provide your own render() method. So in the render() method below, you can add whatever you want.

Column selectCheckBoxColumn =
                new Column(new MyCheckBoxCell()) {

```
               @Override
               public String getValue(MyJSONObject object) {
                  return object.getInternalId();
               }
            };
         MyCellTable.addColumn(selectCheckBoxColumn, "Display title");

.....
.....
.....

   private class MyCheckBoxCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

      @Override
      public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

         /*
          * Always do a null check on the value. Cell widgets can pass null to
          * cells if the underlying data contains a null, or if the data arrives
          * out of order.
          */
         if (value == null) {
            return;
         }

         sb.appendHtmlConstant("<input type='checkbox' name='" + htmlDOMId1 + "'" +
                               " id='" + htmlDOMId1 + "'" +
                               " value='" + value + "'" +
                               "></input>");

      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I really didn't understand your answer, may be i need to clarify my requirement properly. I do not have any checkbox. I have textcells, in each cell I should be able to write text in multiple lines. After entering one line, I want to do press enter to add next line in the SAME cell, similar to TEXTAREA where we can enter multiple lines of data. FYI, we can enter multiple lines of data in EXCEL sheet cell using ALT+ENTER. I want similar thing in CellTable cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the line-breaks (\n) to HTML line breaks (<BR>)

Either you can do this when you save the data on your backend or you can do it in the render method of your **TextAreaEditCell**

Something like that:

```
@Override 
public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) { 

    // Get the view data. 
    Object key = context.getKey(); 
    ViewData viewData = getViewData(key); 
    if (viewData != null && !viewData.isEditing() && value != null 
            && value.equals(viewData.getText())) { 
        clearViewData(key); 
        viewData = null; 
    } 

    if (viewData != null) { 
        String text = viewData.getText(); 
        if (viewData.isEditing()) { 
            /* 
             * Do not use the renderer in edit mode because the value of a text 
             * input element is always treated as text. SafeHtml isn't valid in the 
             * context of the value attribute. 
             */ 
            sb.append(template.input(text, inputLength, inputWidth)); 
        } 
        else { 
            // The user pressed enter, but view data still exists. 

            String escaped_text = text.replace("\n","<BR>").replace("\r","");
            sb.append(renderer.render(escaped_text)); 
        } 
    } else if (value != null) { 
        String escaped_text = value.replace("\n","<BR>").replace("\r","");
        sb.append(renderer.render(escaped_text)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: timeu, as u suggested I used replacement of \n with <BR>. Still there is a little problem. Now multiple lines of info is going to DB as multiple lines. But When the data is displayed in CellTable it is showing as: Key1=Value1|<BR>Key2=Value2|. i.e., BR is visible. But When I click on the cell the info is shown in 2 multiple lines without <BR>. How to avoid this <BR> visibility in CellTable display.

Comment: I suppose the SafeHtmlBuilder in the render method probably escapes the "<" tags of <BR> and that's the reason why it displays "<BR>" instead of a line break. Check out the SafeHTMLBuilder documentation http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html how to not escape HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution of the render method which will display multi line in a TextAreaEditCell. Basically you are splitting the stored string based on the \n character and then joining them appending the 
 tag as a HTML constant for the SafeBuilder.

@Override 
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

```
    // Get the view data. 
    Object key = context.getKey(); 
    ViewData viewData = getViewData(key); 
    if (viewData != null && !viewData.isEditing() && value != null 
            && value.equals(viewData.getText())) { 
        clearViewData(key); 
        viewData = null; 
        /*
         * Render a blank space to force the rendered element to have a height.
         * Otherwise it is not clickable.
         */
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("\u00A0");
    } 

    if (viewData != null) { 
        String text = viewData.getText(); 
        if (viewData.isEditing()) { 
            /* 
             * Do not use the renderer in edit mode because the value of a text 
             * input element is always treated as text. SafeHtml isn't valid in the 
             * context of the value attribute. 
             */ 
            sb.append(template.input(text, inputLength, inputWidth)); 
        } 
        else { 
            // The user pressed enter, but view data still exists. 
            String[] items = text.split("\n");
            for (String item : items) {
                sb.append(renderer.render(item));
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<br/>");
              }
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("\u00A0");

        } 
    } else if (value != null) { 
        String[] items = value.split("\n");
        for (String item : items) {
            sb.append(renderer.render(item));
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<br/>");
          }

        /*
         * Render a blank space to force the rendered element to have a height.
         * Otherwise it is not clickable.
         */
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("\u00A0");
    }

}
```