# GWT : How to add a scrollable TextInputCell to a CellArea?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new to GWT and am changing an existing GWT project.  I have a table which is:
`private final CellTable<Thing> samplesTable`
and several columns, one of which is:
`private final Column<Thing, String> nameColumn`

I instantiate nameColumn like so:
`nameColumn = new Column<Thing, String>(new TextInputCell()) { methods }`

This works fine, but TextInputCell is not scrollable. I want make the text input a scrollable box, so I tried changing the TextInputCell to a TextArea and casting:
`nameColumn = new Column<Thing, String>((Cell<String>) new TextInputCell())`

but of course it failed. I have searched the GWT documents for scrollable text boxes which are also Cells but can't find any.

The other objects in this CellTable are of Cell type, so I can't change the table type. How can I best get a scrollable text area in a Cell to add to a CellTable ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [How to add multiple lines of text in GWT celltable EditTextCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761364/how-to-add-multiple-lines-of-text-in-gwt-celltable-edittextcell)

The code needs tidied up, but it works. It uses SafeHtmlTemlpate so get your head around that - best resource I found for that was "GWT In Action"